# class template - How to write constructors

Tags: c++, templates

What's the diffrence between 1 and 2, 3 and 4?
To me, it works the same.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    T data;
public:
    Foo(T data) : data(data) {}             // 1.
    Foo<T>(T data) : data(data) {}          // 2.
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo)          // 3.
    {
        data = foo.data;
    }
    Foo<T>& operator=(const Foo<T>& foo)    // 4.
    {
        data = foo.data;
    }
};
```

Comment: The key to google is "injected class name."

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are the same.  3 and 4 are the same.  3 and 4 are not constructors, they are assignment operators.

3 and 4 will not be called if you do this:

```
Foo<int> f1;
Foo<int> f2=f1;
```

while 1 and 2 will be.

You need to look up "C++ special member functions" "C++ constructor" "C++ copy constructor" "C++ assignment operator" in the C++ text you are learning from (even google), as you appear to be missing basic vocabulary about these issues.

`=` during construction does not call `operator=`.  Sometimes `ooerator=` will construct implicitly.  Generally you want to implement, `default` or `delete` all 5 of the special member functions, or implement 0 of them.  This is known as the rule of three (five), and as the rule of zero.